# Describing a spin-1 Zeeman split system using a spin-1/2 Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Say we have a spin-1 system. Under no magnetic field, the $m_s=0$ state is separated from the $m_s=\pm1$ states by some amount due to an extra field-independent interaction. When the field is on (assuming it is directed along the z-axis for simplicity), the $m_s=\pm1$ levels split, making one closer to the $m_s=0$ state than the other. Under a large enough magnetic field and working with a narrow enough frequency range, it is possible to ignore one of the three states. effectively considering the system as a spin-1/2 system. Instead of writing
$$H_{Zeeman}=H_0+\gamma B_zS_z$$
where $H_0$ is the extra interaction responsible for the initial splitting between the $m_s=0$ state and the others, and
$$S_z=\hbar\left(\matrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1}\right)$$
we can instead change $S_z$ to its spin-1/2 counterpart:
$$S_z=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left(\matrix{1&0\\0&-1}\right)$$
and simply not write $H_0$,

My question is, **why is this allowed and what do I have to take into account by doing this change?** (e.g. do I need to change the energy coordinates, or do I need to change the value of $\gamma$?)

For context, this approximation is done in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2004.12119). I thought of getting away with the generic explanation in this question since I think there is nothing special about the solid.

Comment: For starters: if $H$ is block diagonal, separate blocks doesn't talk each other; see e.g. (https://www2.physik.uni-muenchen.de/lehre/vorlesungen/sose_21/tensor_networks_21/skript/07-Symmetries-I-Abelian.pdf). Then a constant shift in $H$ is trivial to the dynamics.